# Алгоритм создания экземпляров класса для конкретной задачи

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Бьюсь уже несколько дней с алгоритмом создания экземпляров класса для следующей задачи
вводная: Есть файл в котором последовательно записаны данные.
Перед началом блока данных в файле есть заголовок(Begin) и после части с данными есть конечная часть(End).
также есть блок с флагами, который может быть между Begin и End, а может быть и снаружи этой структуры. Но опытным путём выяснил, что если блок с флагами относится к конкретной структуре, то Offset этого блока с флагами всегда равняется на 0x150 байт больше чем offset структуры к которой он относится.
Самая большая проблема для меня оказалась в том, что по какой-то причине перед блоком с данными может быть несколько заголовков Begin и несколько заголовков End c разными данными в них.
Корректные данные в заголовке считаются из первого Begin и до последнего End.
Написал парсер который возвращает все расшифрованные заголовки в листе.

примерно такого содержания list

```
public class Data
{
    public long offsetBlock { set; get; }
    public string flag { set; get; }
    ....
    public string BeginEnd{ set; get; }
{
```

Такого вот содержания: + описание алгоритма словами

```
Offset: 2C  End игнорируем этот экземпляр.
Offset: 242     End игнорируем этот экземпляр.
Offset: 394     Begin нужно создать экземпляр класса Section и поместить в поле begin значение offset
Offset: 12E6    Begin игнорируем
Offset: 633A    Begin игнорируем
Offset: A892    Begin игнорируем
Offset: AB1E    Flag помещаем в поле flagOffset класса Section
Offset: B250    End помещаем в поле end класса Section. Экземпляр готов, помещаем экземпляр в лист.
Offset: B2A2    Flag игнорируем
Offset: B2F2    Begin нужно создать экземпляр класса Section и поместить в поле begin значение offset
Offset: B344    End помещаем в поле end класса Section. Экземпляр готов, помещаем экземпляр в лист.
Offset: B396    Flag игнорируем
Offset: B3E6    Begin нужно создать экземпляр класса Section и поместить в поле begin значение offset
Offset: B438    End помещаем в поле end класса Section. Экземпляр готов, помещаем экземпляр в лист.
Offset: B48A    Flag игнорируем
Offset: B4DA    Flag здесь до блока Begin 0x150 байт. Значит его нужно будет поместить в блок Section 
Offset: B62A    Begin нужно создать экземпляр класса Section и поместить в поле begin значение offset + добавить данные о флаге
Offset: D87C    Begin игнорируем 
Offset: F9E2    End помещаем в поле end класса Section. Экземпляр готов, помещаем экземпляр в лист.
Offset: FA34    Flag игнорируем 
Offset: FA84    Flag игнорируем 
Offset: FAD4    Begin нужно создать экземпляр класса Section и поместить в поле begin значение offset
Offset: FB26    End помещаем в поле end класса Section. Экземпляр готов, помещаем экземпляр в лист.
Offset: FB78    Flag игнорируем 
Offset: FBC8    Begin нужно создать экземпляр класса Section и поместить в поле begin значение offset
Offset: FC1A    End помещаем в поле end класса Section. Экземпляр готов, помещаем экземпляр в лист.
Offset: FC6C    Flag игнорируем 
Offset: FCBC    Begin нужно создать экземпляр класса Section и поместить в поле begin значение offset
Offset: FD0E    End помещаем в поле end класса Section. Экземпляр готов, помещаем экземпляр в лист.
Offset: FD60    Flag
Offset: FDB0    Begin
Offset: FE02    End
Offset: FE54    Flag
Offset: FEA4    Begin
Offset: FEF6    End
Offset: FF48    Flag
Offset: FF98    Begin
Offset: FFEA    End
Offset: 1003C   Begin
Offset: 1008E   End
Offset: 100E0   Begin
Offset: 10132   End
Offset: 10184   Begin
Offset: 101D6   Begin
Offset: 10228   End
Offset: 1027A   Begin
Offset: 102CC   End
Offset: 1031E   Begin
Offset: 10370   End
Offset: 103C2   Flag
Offset: 10412   Flag
Offset: 10462   Begin
Offset: 104B4   End
Offset: 10506   Flag
Offset: 10556   Flag
Offset: 105A6   Flag
Offset: 105F6   Begin
Offset: 10648   End
```

Offset - от начала файла из которого этот экземпляр создавался.

Мне нужно из этих данных получить реальные значения offset начала и конца блока с данными.
для тестов создал класс

```
public class Section
    {
        public long begin { set; get; } = -1;
        public long end { set; get; } = -1;
        public long flagOffset { set; get; } = -1;
    }
```

хочу в него помещать значения начала и конца блока данных. По сути задача сводиться к созданию экземпляров класса Section c данными begin и End.
Пока не получается придумать алгоритм по которому будут корректно создаваться экземпляры класса Section. У меня получаются либо begin = -1, либо end = -1 и тд.

Comment: А не могли бы Вы пояснить, begin - end могут быть вложенными? Или это плоская структура?

Comment: Почему флаг нельзя разместить сразу после инструкции `BEGIN`. Т. е. `BEGIN; <длина флага (аттрибутов)> (опционально, если константная длина и нет версий); FLAGS; CONTENT (опционально, если флаги — и есть ваш контент); END`. Или ещё можно вместо `begin`/`end` использовать длины блока, т. е. `BEGIN убираем; <длина блока>; ...; END убираем` (это если у вас "плоские" секции).

Comment: @S.H. begin и end не вложенные. Это плоская структура

Comment: @return позицию тех или иных блоков я получаю из файла. Я не могу их поменять.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что нужно в вопросе, но рази интереса потыкал палкой в файлик, получился такой код

```
var fname = @"C:\Dev\Temp\11.txt";

using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fname))){
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string begin = null, offset = null, end = null;
        
        while(!reader.EndOfStream){
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.Contains("Begin")){
                begin = line;
                break;
            }
        }

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();               
            if (line.Contains("Flag"))
                offset = line;
                
            if (line.Contains("End"))
            {
                end = line;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (end != null){
            var section = new Section() {
                begin = Convert.ToInt64(begin.Split(' ')[1], 16),
                flagOffset  = offset != null ? Convert.ToInt64(offset.Split(' ')[1], 16) : -1,
                end = Convert.ToInt64(end.Split(' ')[1], 16)
            };
            Console.WriteLine($"{section.begin} {section.flagOffset} {section.end}");
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе выдает следующее

```
916 43806 45648
45810 -1 45892
46054 -1 46136
46298 -1 63970
64212 -1 64294
64456 -1 64538
64700 -1 64782
64944 -1 65026
65188 -1 65270
65432 -1 65514
65596 -1 65678
65760 -1 65842
65924 -1 66088
66170 -1 66252
66334 -1 66416
66658 -1 66740
67062 -1 67144
```